# Reactjs: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, javascript-objects, dom-events

I added headers on the server side

```
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');

 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods',"OPIONS,GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE");

 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type , Authorization');
```

But I still get the error on reactjs
I used  fetch for send and take data.
Also I used from the header `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'`
On the ractjs

Comment: You need to set your headers in backend side like req.setHeader...

Comment: What are you using backend side?

Comment: You can control your request with the DevTools of chrome. You need to put the header on server and on the another server you do the request.

What do you use of server type ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use pretty good library called `cors` which can do all your configs for you. here check it [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors). you can configure it in your app.js like so:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors());
```

if this does not work, you probably forgot to add `proxy` to your client's `package.json`

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code (no comma after the URL), and setting the header on the client side doesn't help...

Comment: and if it not working too, then he may forgot to add "proxy" to client's `package.json`

Comment: That's on the server side.

Comment: yes, he must configure cors on the server like `app.use(cors())`

Comment: [Edit] your answer to include what the OP should do. My comment was about the code in the current answer, which indicates adding a header to the client request, which will not resolve the CORS error.